# How to make my plugin options available to all the plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I'm starting to make plugins and I'm having trouble with variable scope inside the plugin. I want to be able to access my options from everywhere inside the plugin but not sure how, the var $opts is only visible to that function and my public functions can't access it. Does anyone know how I would do that? 
Thanks in advance, oh and if anyone notices any mistakes in the way I'm making the plugin don't hesitate to mention them :D

```
//@@@@ Start of myViewport Plugin @@@@\\
(function($) {

  $.fn.myViewport = function(options) {
    var $opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.myViewport.defaults, options);

    //Plugin Here
    return this.each(function() {           

        alert('Initialising Plugin!' + $opts.privateText + $opts.publicText);
        myPrivateFunction();
    });
  };

  // private functions
  function myPrivateFunction($opts) {
        alert($opts.privateText);
  };

  // public functions
  $.fn.myViewport.myPublicFunction = function() {
        alert($opts.publicText);
  };

  // plugin defaults
  $.fn.myViewport.defaults = {
    privateText: 'This is a text from the privateText defaults',
    publicText: 'This is a text from the publicText defaults'
  };

})(jQuery);
//@@@@ End of myViewport Plugin @@@@\\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.myViewport = function(options) {
    var o = $.extend(vp, $.fn.myViewport.defaults, options);

    //Plugin Here
    return this.each(function() {           

        alert('Initialising Plugin!' + o.privateText + o.publicText);
        myPrivateFunction();
    });
  };

  var vp = $.fn.myViewport;

  // private functions
  function myPrivateFunction() {
        alert(vp.privateText);
  };

  // public functions
  vp.myPublicFunction = function() {
        alert(vp.defaults.publicText);
  };

  // plugin defaults
  vp.defaults = {
    privateText: 'This is a text from the privateText defaults',
    publicText: 'This is a text from the publicText defaults'
  };

})(jQuery);
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NzBAe/1/).**

Comment: Thats great thanks, could you explain it a bit I don't understand what you changed and what is my var o = $.extend(vp, $.fn.myViewport.defaults, options); for I could just use vp. right?

Comment: If I call the plugin like this: 

$(document).myViewport({
    privateText: 'New Text'           
});  Then it doesn't use this new text.

Comment: `var o` is the options within the `$.fn.myViewport` function, and `vp` is so you don't have to use `$.fn.myViewport` everytime. Works ok for me : http://jsfiddle.net/NzBAe/2/

Comment: If I declare new options before using a public function it doesnt use the new one it uses the old one. $(document).myViewport.myPublicFunction(); this doesnt work properly, any way to fix that?